# Selenium Web Driver. Problem with simultaneous requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, selenium-webdriver

The essence of the program is that it receives an HTTP request with query parameters such as "url" and "canCache".
Then the program has to open a new tab, go to the url and take a screenshot of the page and then close the tab. Problem: with simultaneous queries, the results are either mixed or result in an error.

Here are my 2 pieces of my code.

#schedule_gen.py

```
import urllib
from io import BytesIO
from cache import cache_schedule
import logging


def schedule_png_gen(url, can_cache, driver):
    original_window = driver.current_window_handle

    # Setting up Selenium Web Driver.
    # Running in windowless mode, configuring the browser type (Firefox), getting the link
    driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
    driver.get(url)

    # Added a script that measures page height and width.
    # Made to avoid the error when the 'body' tag ends where it shouldn't.
    required_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
    required_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
    driver.set_window_size(required_width, required_height)

    # Screenshot of the page, adding the .png extension and encoding special characters
    screen = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
    screen_buffer = BytesIO(screen)
    screen_size = screen_buffer.getbuffer().nbytes
    url_upd1 = url + '.png'
    url_upd2 = urllib.parse.quote(url_upd1, safe='')

    # If you want to cache the page, call the cache schedule method.
    # The input parameters of the method are described in cache.py
    if can_cache:
        cache_schedule(url_upd2, screen_buffer, screen_size)
    # Resetting the window size to avoid taking the screenshot of the previous page's size.
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

    # Closing the current tab.
    driver.close()

    # Switching back to the original tab.
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    return screen
```

#main.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from cache import get_cached_schedule
from schedule_gen import schedule_png_gen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# Running the Flask application.
app = Flask(__name__)

# Request handling.
@app.route('/schedule', methods=['GET'])
def schedule():
    # Processing query parameters.
    url = request.args.get('url')
    can_cache = request.args.get('canCache', False)

    if url == None:
        return ("No url")

    # Checking for the existence of a screenshot in the Minio database.
    image_data = get_cached_schedule(url)
    if image_data:
        return Response(image_data, mimetype='image/png')
    else:
         screen = schedule_png_gen(url, can_cache, driver)
         return Response(screen, mimetype='image/png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8800, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Initially I tried adding a time delay, thinking that the mixing is caused by different loading speeds of the sites, but it did not give any results